# Multicriteria search for keyword and copy to another sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a macro that allows a user to search through the data in an Excel worksheet using keywords, then copy all results with that keyword to a new sheet. I have been able to get the basic search, sheet generation and renaming down with some help, however I would also like to include the ability to exclude and include results based on factors other than keywords.

For instance: search for keyword "glasses", only include items that have the words "I need", "I want", "I require" in front of it.

or
search for keyword "glasses" and do not return items that have "already have", "do not need", etc.

Basically I want to be able to hone the search a bit more to allow the samples to be more precise. Does anyone have any ideas of how to include exceptions and inclusions like this into the macro?

```
Option Compare Text

Public Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
' set variables
Dim Continue As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sheetIndex As Long


sheetIndex = 2 'start on the second sheet index to keep from overwriting data sheet

Continue = vbYes
    Do While Continue = vbYes 'set condition to cause loop

        findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?")) 'prompt user for input
        n = CStr(InputBox("Exclusions?")) 'asks user for any exceptions
        LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub 'end execution if no entry
        j = 1
    For i = 1 To LastLine 'loop through interactions
        For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
            If (InStr(1, cell, n, 1) = 0) Then
                toCopy = False
            If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
                toCopy = True
            End If
        Next
        If toCopy = True Then
            Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = UCase(findWhat) 'name sheet based on keyword entered
            Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sheetIndex).Rows(j) 'copy interactions to new sheet
            j = j + 1
        End If
        toCopy = False
    Next i
    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1 'increment sheetindex by one
    Continue = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) 'prompt user to see if more input required
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a bit to your test/compare loop:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
    ' set variables
    Dim Continue As Long
    Dim findWhat As String
    Dim LastLine As Long
    Dim toCopy As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim sheetIndex As Long
    Dim inclusions() As String
    Dim exclusions() As String
    Dim testString As Variant
    Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
    Dim matchFound As Boolean

    sheetIndex = 2 'start on the second sheet index to keep from overwriting data sheet

    '--- you can create these from your input box or cells on a worksheet
    '    (the code below tests for the case: "I want glasses but do not need them"
    inclusions = Split("I need,I want,I require", ",", , vbTextCompare)
    exclusions = Split("already have,do not need", ",", , vbTextCompare)

    Continue = vbYes
    Do While Continue = vbYes 'set condition to cause loop

        findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?")) 'prompt user for input
        LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub 'end execution if no entry
        j = 1
        For i = 1 To LastLine 'loop through interactions
            matchFound = False
            For Each cell In Range("BU1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
                pos1 = InStr(cell.Text, findWhat)
                If pos1 <> 0 Then
                    '--- now check for inclusions/exclusions
                    '     ---> add checks for an empty inclusion/exclusion list
                    '          and what you should do about it
                    For Each testString In inclusions
                        pos2 = InStr(cell.Text, testString)
                        If (pos2 > 0) And (pos2 < pos1) Then  'checks before match
                            matchFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next testString
                    For Each testString In exclusions
                        pos2 = InStr(cell.Text, testString)
                        If (pos2 > 0) And (pos2 > pos1) Then  'checks after match
                            matchFound = False                'set False to skip this
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next testString
                    If matchFound Then
                        Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = UCase(findWhat) 'name sheet based on keyword entered
                        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sheetIndex).Rows(j) 'copy interactions to new sheet
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next i
        sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1 'increment sheetindex by one
        Continue = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion) 'prompt user to see if more input required
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight here. It's truely helpful. I see how the inclusions and exclusions are compared, but do not completely understand how I would enter them into the search?

Comment: The inclusions/exclusions are separate from the search term, so you have to deal with them separately -- and how it makes sense to you. Your inclusions/exclusions can be static (i.e. exactly as coded above, so that the user has no control over them), or user-specified. You can choose how to ask your users what to include/exclude. A few examples would be to create two ranges on a worksheet for inclusive phrases and exclusive phrases, or a pop-up form with a set of phrases next to check boxes that the user can select, or ask the user to enter a comma-separated list in a simple InputBox.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think I am going to go for the check box version just to limit the amount of work the use has to do. Also, when I try running the above code, I get an error telling me to debug 
If matchFound Then
                        Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = UCase(findWhat)

I tried, adding, If matchFound = True Then..... etc. but it's still throwing an error. Are you getting that error as well?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? The code in that section is renaming the worksheet (index 2) to the search term (and it worked fine for me, no changes to your original code).

Comment: Yeah it worked well previously yet now is throwing error "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range". I did have to change part of the code to check beginning at range "BY1" instead of "BU1" but other than that, have made no changes.

Comment: The subscript out of range error would indicate to me that whatever you think `Sheets(2)` is, Excel is disagreeing with you (as in `Sheets(2)` does not exist). Perhaps use the name of the sheet as the index instead?

Comment: Ahh, okay. I need to set it to somehow automatically generate a new sheet at the end of the workbook before naming, that way it will have a sheet to name. Thank you again, for all your help and time!